# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, architecture, frontend

I'm trying to access `getData()` from `GetDataService` in my React function component `DataComponent()` but i keep getting this error and i'm not knowing how to solve this.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')

GetDataService

```
export default class GetDataService {

private dataRepo: DataRepository

constructor(dataRepo: DataRepository) {
    this.dataRepo = dataRepo;
}

getData() {
    return this.dataRepo.getData();
  }
}
```

Repository I'm injecting

```
export default interface DataRepository {

   getData: () => Promise<Response>;
}
```

Class that fetchs my data and implements the Repository

```
export default class DataFetch implements DataRepository {

dataurl = 'http://localhost:8080/data';

getData(): Promise<Response> {
   return Promise.resolve(fetch(this.dataurl));
   }
}
```

Component

```
function DataComponent() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getDataService = new GetDataService(dataRepo);

    useEffect(() => {
           
        getDataService.getData()
            .then(res =>  {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Data ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                setData(data);
            })

    }, [])
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems like `dataRepo` is undefined when you create a new instance of `GetDataService`. Where are you instantiating `dataRepo` within the component? Is the instantiation async? If so, you'll need to account for that and wait for `dataRepo` to be instantiated before creating an instance of `GetDataService`, likely with another `useEffect`.

Comment: In this line `const getDataService = new GetDataService(dataRepo);` where does `dataRepo` come from? because it appears it is undefined.

Comment: I'm instantiating dataRepo in my Component file with let dataRepo: DataRepository;. React doesn't show me the error in my console only in my browser. I'm new to the Dependency Injection Topic so I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.